# The merge into command on Snowflake loads only null values when loading data from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm having issues when running the command `MERGE INTO` on Snowflake. The data is located in a bucket on S3. The files format are `.snappy.parquet`.

The command runs well, it identifies the files in S3, but it loads only NULL values to the table. The total row numbers are also good.

I confirmed that `@myExternalStageToS3` points to the right location by running a query which returned the expected values:

```
SELECT
    $1:DAY,
    $1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
     $1:SOURCE,
    $1:PLATFORM,
    $1:LOB
@myExternalStageToS3
(FILE_FORMAT => 'sf_parquet_format')
```

As it is a new table with no records, the condition uses INSERT.

```
MERGE INTO myTable as target USING
(
    SELECT
    $1:DAY,
    $1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
    $1:SOURCE,
    $1:PLATFORM,
    $1:LOB
    FROM @myExternalStageToS3
    (FILE_FORMAT => 'sf_parquet_format')
  ) as src 
        ON target.CHANNEL_CATEGORY = src.$1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY 
        AND target.SOURCE = src.$1:SOURCE 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
DAY= src.$1:DAY
,CHANNEL_CATEGORY= src.$1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY
,SOURCE= src.$1:SOURCE
,PLATFORM= src.$1:PLATFORM
,LOB= src.$1:LOB
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
      DAY,
      CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
      SOURCE,
      PLATFORM,
      LOB
) VALUES
(
  src.$1:DAY,
  src.$1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
  src.$1:SOURCE,
  src.$1:PLATFORM,
  src.$1:LOB
);
```

The `sf_parque_format` was created with these details:

```
create or replace file format sf_parquet_format
    type = 'parquet'
    compression = auto;
```

Do you have any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query inside `USING` part was altered(data type casts and aliases):

```
MERGE INTO myTable as target USING (
    SELECT
    $1:DAY::TEXT AS DAY,
    $1:CHANNEL_CATEGORY::TEXT AS CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
    $1:SOURCE::TEXT AS SOURCE,
    $1:PLATFORM::TEXT AS PLATFROM,
    $1:LOB::TEXT AS LOB
    FROM @myExternalStageToS3
    (FILE_FORMAT => 'sf_parquet_format')
  ) as src 
        ON target.CHANNEL_CATEGORY = src.CHANNEL_CATEGORY 
        AND target.SOURCE = src.SOURCE 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
 DAY= src.DAY
,PLATFORM= src.PLATFORM
,LOB= src.LOB
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (
      DAY,
      CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
      SOURCE,
      PLATFORM,
      LOB
) VALUES  (
  src.DAY,
  src.CHANNEL_CATEGORY,
  src.SOURCE,
  src.PLATFORM,
  src.LOB
);
```

The `UPDATE` part does not require `,CHANNEL_CATEGORY= src.CHANNEL_CATEGORY ,SOURCE= src.SOURCE` as condition is already met by `ON` clasue.